# Browserify jQuery UI from CDN

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, browserify, browserify-shim, grunt-browserify

I'd like to use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) but continue loading jQuery and jQuery UI from [Google's CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/) instead of concatenating the code into my files or my vendor bundle. I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work.

I am getting this error when loading `foo.js`:

> Cannot find module 'jquery-ui'

These are the relevant files:

#### package.json

```
{
  // ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify-shim": "^3.8.11",
    "deamdify": "^0.1.1",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-browserify": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.10.5"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "global:$",
    "jquery-ui": {
      "depends": "jquery",
      "exports": null
    }
  }
}
```

### Gruntfile.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        browserify: {
            options: {
                external: [
                    'jquery',
                    'jquery-ui'
                ],
                transform: [
                    'browserify-shim',
                    'deamdify'
                ]
            },
            app: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'public/js',
                    src: '*.js',
                    dest: 'assets/js'
                }]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
};
```

#### foo.js

```
'use strict';

var $ = require('jquery');
require('jquery-ui');

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('Hello world');

    $('button').button();
});
```

I have also tried `exclude` instead of `external` and it produces the same results. Any way to achieve this?

I realize there's also the [debowerify](https://github.com/eugeneware/debowerify) transform but I'd like to avoid Bower if possible.

**Update**: I've noticed that commenting out the `require` call to `'jquery-ui'` will work because jQuery exposes the global `$` and `jQuery` by default but I thought the whole point of writing code in CommonJS or even AMD format is to avoid depending on globals?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `external` block here. That's for excluding various libraries for your bundle...which is why when using the `require('jquery-ui')` with the `external` block you're getting that error.

What you want is to expose the global `jquery-ui` to your browserify builds, as [here in the docs](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim#multi-shim-example-including-dependencies).

The browserify-shim config would be:

```
"browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "global:$", // this is only if you're also loading jQuery via CDN/<script> tag
    "jquery-ui": {
      "depends": "jquery" 
    }
  }
```